# What is the correct value of max_size() for a fixed capacity custom STL container?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm writing a custom circular buffer implementation with fixed capacity (fixed at runtime by call to constructor, no resize methods) and want it to be STL-compatible.
My goal is to make it a [Random Access Container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessContainer.html). Additionally I want it to have the specific interface of an [Back Insertion Sequence](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/BackInsertionSequence.html), but without being a sequence (no resize and inserting/erasing at arbitrary positions, ...). So it would only be an extended Random Access Container.
After reading some questions about **max_size()** and **size()**, I'm still a little confused.

My current idea:
**size()**: number of elements contained in buffer
**max_size()**: capacity of buffer (maximum number of elements it can hold)

Is this correct (conforming to standard / STL)? Or do I have to handle it like (std::)array with size() == max_size()?

Comment: for `std::array`, `size()` == `max_size()` because an array's size is fixed, it cannot have either more or fewer objects than it's specified to have (unless you use tricks like manually calling destructors, but then the array doesn't know about what you've done).

Comment: So when you say "fixed capacity": you have different options according to whether you mean the capacity is fixed at run time by passing a value into the constructor, or fixed at compile time (either one hard-coded value for the library or as a template parameter).

Comment: @SteveJessop: Updated the question to state this more clearly. Capacity is fixed at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard is quite clear on the meaning of `max_size()` in C++11 Table 96:

> `distance(begin(), end())` for the largest possible container

If, like `std::array`, the size is a property of the container type (e.g. specified by a template parameter), then that should be the same as `size()`. If you can instantiate the same type with various sizes, then it should be the largest allowed size.

I would follow the example of the standard containers, and have a `capacity()` function to tell you the capacity.

Comment: For certain values of "possible" -- I don't think it's actually intended to be a violation of the standard if you return `SIZE_MAX` for `vector<char>::max_size()` when in fact global operator new is incapable in principle of making an allocation larger than `SIZE_MAX/2`.

Comment: Nice explanation. So the solution would be size(): current number of elements in buffer, max_size(): static system specific value for a maximal size of any circularbuffer<T>, capacity(): max. number of elements of this instance of circularbuffer<T>?

Comment: @EnnoGröper: Or, like `std::array`, make a `circularbuffer<T,N>` and return `N` as `max_size`. You cannot be wrong in following in the STL footsteps ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Thanks, but in my use case the capacity isn't known at compile time and in a container with the interface of a Back Insertion Sequence size() is mutable. My container is more like std::vector than like std::array.

Comment: @EnnoGröper: I did not suggest not making `size()` mutable, I only suggested having a upper-bound at compile-time. If this is not possible, then of course you should not do it ;)

Answer (score 3):

`max_size` doesn't relate to a specific instance of the container type. It is the maximum size that the type can handle, according to whatever implementation details limit it (the max value of `size_type` if nothing else).

`vector` can reserve space that isn't currently used, and for that reason it has a `capacity()` function. This isn't part of any of the container concepts though, because other containers (`deque`, `list`) don't reserve space.